Get content from Azure file shares and write into SQL table using Power Automate
Is there a way to parse the contents of the file shares and write to a SQL table? I'm able to copy the .csv file to a destination (blob, drive) but I'm struggling with the column mapping.
My source is a file share in Azure file and my desired destination in a SQL table. Thanks!


Have you tried any approach?

Did you use Storage Connector?

To send file from Azure File storage to sql, you can use below design:

split(body('Get_file_content'),decodeUriComponent('%0D%0A'))


Compose 2:
split(first(outputs('Compose')), ',')

Select (Code view/Peek code):
{
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@outputs('Compose')",
        "select": {
            "@{outputs('Compose_2')[0]}": "@split(item(), ',')?[0]",
            "@{outputs('Compose_2')[1]}": "@split(item(), ',')?[1]"
        }
    }
}

In Parse Json, set(generate from sample) the output of Select:


Then:

Next action use compose to just show done as output .
Output:



Here, I have converted csv to json manually, there are many connectors which automatically.
For further information also refer SO-Thread1 and SO-Thread2.
